# How to download file on android with PHP force download

Tags: android, download, force-download

I make an application , this can download file form server.

use this code >>>

```
public int startDownload(String url, String filename) {
// create url connector
URL u;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
try {
  u = new URL(url + filename);
  HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
  c.setRequestMethod("GET");
  c.setDoOutput(true);
  c.connect();
  InputStream in = c.getInputStream();
  m_lMaxDownloadSz = c.getContentLength();
  FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(new File(FILE_PATH, filename));

  m_bCancelDownload = false;
  m_lCurrentDownloadSz = 0;
  int len = 0;
  while ((len = in.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0) {

    // if download is canceled.
    if (m_bCancelDownload) {
      f.close();
      c.disconnect();
      return FILE_DOWNLOAD_CANCELED;
    }
    if (knot++ >= PROGRESS_STEP) {
      knot = 0;
      myProgressDialog.setProgress(GetDownloadStatus());
    }
    f.write(buffer, 0, len);
    m_lCurrentDownloadSz += len;
  }

  f.close();
  c.disconnect();

} catch (Exception e) {
  return FILE_DOWNLOAD_FAILED;
}

if (GetDownloadStatus() == 100) {
  return FILE_DOWNLOAD_FINISHED;
} else {
  return FILE_DOWNLOAD_FAILED;
}
```

}

and I want to use with PHP force download , but it not work , ordinary it use with file path like 'app/aaa.apk' it work! ,and I change to PHP file like 'php/forcedl.php' it not work.

I needs to use with php force download, How do I use?

ps. i have little english language skill , cause english language is not my main language

thank you

Comment: What happens if you try to upen this url in browser?

Comment: i open www.xxx.com/x.php in android browser , it show submit to download file.apk

ps. in file php > header forcedownload to an apk file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discover for my answer
android-Java Code
__example:

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];         
        String url = "http://www.bla-bla.com/forcedownload.php"


            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                filesize = execute.getEntity().getContentLength();
                fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(new File(FILE_PATH, "file_copyformserver.apk"));

                 while ((len = content.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) > 0) {
                     fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, len);
                     Thread.sleep(100);
                 }

                fileOutput.close();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

php file
__example:

```
      $file = '/home/bla-bla/domains/bla-bla.com/file/file.apk'; //not public folder
      if (file_exists($file)) {
         header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
         header('Content-Type: application/vnd.android.package-archive');
         header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
         header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
         header('Expires: 0');
         header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
         header('Pragma: public');
         header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
         ob_clean();
         flush();
         readfile($file);
         exit;
     }
```

this is short code , sorry if cannot run. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps not the best way to do it, but have you considered renaming the file upon successfully downloading it? I haven't tried it, but I believe you can do it using the `File.renameTo()` method in Android.

Here's some pseudo code that I think will work, can't try it out right now though:

```
File.renameTo(new File(FILE_PATH, filename.replace(".apk", ".php")));
```

Comment: cannot use rename 
_________
two way to download_____
1. android app. --> .apk______
2. android app. --> .php* --> .apk
__
* .php will read an apk file (php force download)
____
i want to use second way to download file 
____
i use that download function it download .php to my device not .apk

Comment: I misunderstood your question then, sorry.