# Prepare Binary file to send to android from Server

Tags: php, android, json, phpexcel

****Please check that, this question refers to transfer file from server directory to android, not via url straight***

I have seen few questions, examples referring how to transfer file "file.xls" from www.xxx.com/file.xls. But in my case, I have created the binary file as :

```
         $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $objWriter->save('record.xlsx');
        exit;
```

So, file "record.xlsx" is created in my server directory. I am trying to pull this file from android. as:

```
       HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
       HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://my url that creates the file");

      try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
            InputStream data = response.getEntity().getContent();
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            ByteStreams.copy(data, output);
         } finally {
           Closeables.closeQuietly(output);
         }
```

What I need is to get the file "record.xlsx" as the stream. Any idea, what should be done to the file (i.e., adding header - content type : json) or any other ideas please.
File in server is created perfectly as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloading Image as Stream code snip :

```
try {
        //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
        //this is the file to be downloaded
        URL url = new URL("http://mtetno.com/file");

        //create the new connection
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //set up some things on the connection
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        //and connect!
        urlConnection.connect();

        //set the path where we want to save the file
        //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
        //sd card.
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
        //which we want to save the file as.
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"somefile.ext");

        //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //this is the total size of the file
        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        //variable to store total downloaded bytes
        int downloadedSize = 0;

        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

        //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
                updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

        }
        //close the output stream when done
        fileOutput.close();

//catch some possible errors...
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: code works like champ.Further - In php side, I have added the headers from this link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348006/how-to-download-file-on-android-with-php-force-download